# Why is my If statement being ignored in my For loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  std::vector<int> nums = {2,4,3,6,1,9,7};

  double evenR = 0;
  double oddR = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++ ) {

    evenR = nums[i]%2;
    std::cout << evenR;

    if (evenR = 0) {
        std::cout << "YAY";
        std::cout << nums[i] << " is even!";
    }

   }

}
```

When running it prints out evenR with multiple iterations of it equaling "0". So I have no idea why my if statement refuses to run?

Comment: Do you know the difference between `=` and `==`?

Comment: [Turn on your compiler warnings](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8uz2FN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ uses "==" for checking if something is equal to something else. A single "=" is an assignment. You are assigning evenR to 0, not checking it.

Comment: To be precise, he is assigning it, *then* checking it. The return value of the assignment is equal to the value assigned, which in this case is always 0, which is why control never enters the body of the`for` loop. Had he used `if(evenR=1)`, the body would *always* run.